Why does changing TargetFramework prevent my hello world program from outputting to the console?
System setup
I am using:

VSCode 1.90.0
MacOS Sonoma 14.5
macos workload 14.2.8053/8.0.100
dotnet SDK 8.0.301

Hello World application
I am new to C# and .net. To introduce my issue, I've created an application using dotnet new console -n HelloWorld
There are 2 files:
HelloWorld.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Program.cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

I use dotnet run and see "Hello, World!" in the console, fantastic.
Problem begins
In setting up another program using the NAPS2 SDK for document scanners, I get the following error:
Unhandled exception. NAPS2.Scan.Exceptions.DriverNotSupportedException:
Unsupported driver: Apple. Make sure you're using the right framework target (e.g. net8-macos10.15 for the Apple driver).

So, inside of the .csproj file, I changed <TargetFramework> to net8-macos10.15. I then get another error:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.macOS.Sdk/14.2.8053/tools/msbuild/macOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(612,3): error : 
A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file.

I then add an ApplicationId, and my .csproj file looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8-macos10.15</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ApplicationId>my.application.ID</ApplicationId>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

When I use dotnet run, the document scanning program starts, but nothing is printed to the console, and the application freezes. Thus, I created the HelloWorld example to test the configuration. If I use the same Program.cs file that just prints "Hello, World!", but change the <TargetFramework> to net8.0-macos10.15 (and add <ApplicationId>), I see no output.
Question
Why does changing <TargetFramework> from net8.0 to net8-macos10.15 result in no output from the hello world script? I would like to understand so that I can use net8-macos10.15 to develop the document scanning application.
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I attempted to run a hello world application. I changed the <TargetFramework> to net8-macos10.15, but the console has no output.
net8.0-macos10.15 does not work either
I ran dotnet restore and dotnet build and both were successful.

Does running the executable in the bin folder work?

Yes. 'Hello, World!' appears in the console.
The path to the executable was ./bin/Debug/net8.0-macos10.15/osx-arm64/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld
